# Postgresql. Find first entry for each unique ID | Date that matches a set of criteria

Tags: postgresql

Sorry if this has been answered but I'm finding it difficult to phrase the question without an example.  I have a set of IDs that I keep information (if it's available) for every hour of every day.  I'm trying to conduct a daily study where specific hours are more relevant than others, so I would like to take the daily data for each ID and filter it by a specified list of times and if there is no data at the first time in the list, check if the next time in the list has data, until data is found at one of the times or no data is available for any of the specified times.  For example

ID | Data_Date      | Data_Time      | Some_data

1    1/4/2015         10:00:00          Z

1    1/4/2015         12:00:00          Z

1    1/5/2015         12:00:00          A

1    1/5/2015         13:00:00          B

2    1/5/2015         13:00:00          C

2    1/5/2015         11:00:00          D

I'd like to take the data from 12:00:00 if available, otherwise use 11:00:00 and if neither exist use 13:00:00.  10:00:00 will not be in the list of times I care about so it is ignored. The query should return

ID | Data_Date      | Data_Time      | Some_data

1    1/4/2015         12:00:00           Z

1    1/5/2015         12:00:00           A

2    1/5/2015         11:00:00           D

It is not the case that it is always the earliest time.  If this is unclear I'll do my best to elaborate.  Any assistance is appreciaed

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this helps you or not since you may have tried it already, but it is a starting point that may help you and I'm hopping we can discuss ideas and work together to solve this (two heads are better than one) :

```
with raw as (select '12:00:00'::time as starting_hour)
select id, data_date, data_time, some_data
from test, raw
where data_time = 
    case when data_time = starting_hour  
        then data_time
        else 
            case when data_time = starting_hour + '-1h'
                then data_time
                else  
                    case when data_time = starting_hour + '1h'
                        then data_time
                        else null
                    end
            end
    end;
```

This will give you 12:00, 11:00 and 13:00. We just need to stop searching when it finds rows that match one of the hours. I'll keep on trying :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the effort.  I was hoping for an elegant solution, and the list of times may end up being about 10 elements